# I can't turn my python script to an executable

Tags: python, raspbian

I have a python script using pygame, os, random, time, and sys and I want to turn it into an executable that can run on any operating system (mainly windows and linux), including computers that dont have python installed. I'm doing this on a raspberry pi, python 3.9.2.

Ive tried pyinstaller, cx_Freeze, and nuitka. Pyinstaller would create a folder with no executable, cx_Freeze made an executable that wouldn't run, and nuitka made a bin file that I failed to turn into an executable. How can I turn my python script into an executable?

Comment: You cannot make an executable that runs on multiple operating systems.  Each runs on the system where it was built, because it includes the Python binary.  If `Pyinstaller` didn't work, then you did it wrong.  Show us what you did.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I ran "pyinstaller --onedir --windowed /home/pi/script.py", this time i ran it there was an executable that would make a pygame window, but the window would instantly dissapear.